# Regex : Replace ; from word if word does not start with &

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to use Regex in javascript. Lets take this scenario,

```
str = "This; is; John; &amp; Jane;"
```

The result I need,

```
str= "This* is* John* &amp; Jane*"
```

This is what I have tried,

```
str.replace(/\^(?!&)\w+;\s/g, "*");
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
str.replace(/(^|\s)([^&]\S+?);(?=$|\s)/g, "$1$2*")
```

You cannot do that without capturing groups because that would require a lookbehind assertion, which Javascript doesn't support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
str.replace(/((^| )[^&]\w+?);/g, "$1*");
```